# Error after transaction LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, transactions

I am doing transaction. Ticket contains ID(auto increment), type_ticket, ID_customer.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{ 
      ticket addTicket = new ticket()
                            {
                                type_ticket = x,
                                ID_customer = idNum
                            };
      db.ticket.Add(addTicket);
      db.SaveChanges(); //error here
      //... some other inserts to database

      scope.Complete();
}
```

If I use this transaction first time everything works fine. But if I use this transaction second time for add second Ticket I have this error:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Ticket class code:

```
  public partial class ticket
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int type_ticket { get; set; }
    public int ID_customer { get; set; }
}
```

In my database is ticket.ID set AUTO_INCREMENT
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code for your ticket class? Arecyou sure the id is being incremented each time?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I uploaded my qestion. Please take a look.